# Converting a string to a list separated by spaces

Tags: python

Say I have a string like this

```
s="a b c de fgh"
```

Now I want to convert it to a list like this

`list1=['a','b','c','de','fgh']`

That is I will separate the characters when there's a space and make them a string of its own and store them in a list. Is there any easier way to do this in a single line command or so rather than iterating over the string and break it up and add it to the list whenever a space is found?

Comment: `s.split()`...?

Answer (score 1):

`split` does exactly that:

```py
result = s.split()
```